# jsPDF add more pages with another code in it

Tags: jquery, jspdf

Hi please how is possible to do this in jsPDF?

```
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [892, 1263]);
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  pdf.addPage();

  // so much of another code?

  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  pdf.addPage();

  // so much of another code?

  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
```

This doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
pdf.addPage();
```

[Working JSFIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/yfHF8/)